# Failing to get updated contents of a file after gulp stream completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to bump the version number in my package.json file, then use the update version number to create a new git tag. Whenever I run the bump task, the git tag created was of the old version number, not the bumped one.

I'm using the `gulp-load-plugins` to register all my plugins and map them to `$`, rather then having to declare them by hand. So instead of `var bump = require("gulp"); ... bump()` I just use `$.bump()`.

**Attempt #1**
My initial code looked like this.

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('bump', function() {
  gulp.src(['package.json'])
    .pipe($.bump())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

  var config = require('./package.json');
  $.git.tag('v' + config.version, 'Version message');
  $.util.log("tag added: " + config.version);
});
```

**Attempt #2**
Some googling made it seem like it was an async vs sync issue, so after reading [this](http://cameronspear.com/blog/handling-sync-tasks-with-gulp-js/) blog post I created two tasks to test this out.

`tag` depended on `bump` completing, with the big change being the return statement in the bump task. The log output shows them being executed in order, but the issue remains.

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('bump', function() {
  return gulp.src(['package.json'])
    .pipe($.bump())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});    

gulp.task('tag',['bump'], function() {
  var config = require('./package.json');
  $.git.tag('v' + config.version, 'Version message');
  $.util.log("tag added: " + config.version);
});
```

**Attempt #3**
I also tried moving the git tag logic into the .on('close') event from bump, but that doesn't solve my problem either.

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('bump', function() {
  return gulp.src(['package.json'])
    .pipe($.bump())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .on('close', function () {
      var config = require('./package.json');
      $.git.tag('v' + config.version, 'Version message');
      $.util.log("tag added: " + config.version);
    });
});
```

**Attempt #4**
Also tried [Mangled-Deutz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133539/276681) suggestion to not use `require('package.json')` since require might be caching the result. I tried using node file system's [readFile()](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) method, but this too was not successful.

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('bump', function() {
  gulp.src(['package.json'])
    .pipe($.bump())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

  fs.readFile("./package.json", {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, data) {
    var config = JSON.parse(data);
    $.git.tag('v' + config.version, 'Version message');
    $.util.log("tag added: " + config.version);
  });
});
```

So any idea where the problem is? Is it still an async vs sync issue and I'm doing something incorrectly? I'd prefer to have the logic in just one task, but if they only way to accomplish this is two, then so be it.

I'm new to gulp and how streams work, so if my title doesn't make sense let me know. I'd like to update it so it is more relevant to search results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are quite likely bitten by the fact that [require uses caching](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)...

Your `require('package.json')` call likely returns you the (cached) version prior to `bump()` action. You should rather try reading it directly (eg: avoiding require).

**UPDATE**

The following **does** work as expected - as suggested above:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('bump', function() {
  return gulp.src(['package.json'])
    .pipe($.bump())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('tag', ['bump'], function() {
// This doesn't work, because require uses caching
//  var config = require('./package.json');
  var config = fs.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf-8');
  console.warn(config);
});
```

Comment: I just tested this using node's file system, which still uses require, and still got the old version of the version number. I'll add the code block I tested with to my main post.

Comment: Your last example (#4) is not good either, as you are no longer waiting for bump to complete! (and these are two different issues). Try again your #2 example, and use something like fs.readFileSync instead of require('package.json').

Comment: I tried that also but didn't put it in as an example. Same result. I'll update the post later with it just to cover all scenarios. Could it be something outside of this code snippet that's causing this? I'm using this logic in a small gulp helper [utility](https://github.com/jarekb84/GulpUtilityBelt/blob/master/gulpfile.js),care to take a look?

Comment: I updated the answer with a working example from your #2, using fs (and not require). It *does* work.

Comment: Ah, you broke it out into two tasks. I'll give that a shot when I get home. Any idea if this is possible to do within a single task?

Comment: Just tested and verified as working. I'd still like a method that doesn't require multiple tasks to accomplish this, so I'll continue to use the gulp-tap plugin solution.

Comment: Doing it "in one task" (at least before the new package.json file is written) causes a problem: you are going to git tag BEFORE the file is written - which is likely not what you want. This is not a gulp problem per-se, but rather a logic problem here...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the [gulp-tap](https://github.com/geejs/gulp-tap) plugin which lets you access the pipe stream and read/modify it. While this does what I want it to, I'd still like to know if there's a non-plugin method of achieving this or what the issue was with my other attempts.

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('bump', function() {
  gulp.src(['package.json'])
    .pipe($.bump())
    .pipe($.tap( function (file, t) {
        var config = JSON.parse(file.contents.toString());
        $.git.tag('v' + config.version, 'Version message');
        $.util.log("new tag " + config.version);
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: As commented above, this will `git tag` before the package.json file with the new version is written - which is likely not what you want.

Comment: @mangled-deutz true that it will get tag before the package.json file is written to disk, but it doesn't matter since it's accessing the in memory stream after the bump task updates the config. This is working for me now in the git repo I mentioned in my other comment.

Comment: If you are happy with the result, then that's it :-) - now, it seems a little bit strange to tag something with, say, version 1.0.0 while the commited package.json file would indicate this is version 0.9.0. Anyhow, best regards.